# Вывод данных за пределами iframe с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт на JS, который генерирует iframe. В этом iframe есть ссылки. Нужно реализовать следующее: по клику на эти ссылке нужно выводить popup на весь экран, т.е. как-то затрагивать класс вне iframe.
Как изнутри iframe-а добраться к основным элементам?

Или можно ли как-то из основного кода как-то отлавливать клики по ссылкам в iframe? Я уже много вариантов перепробовал, но что-то они не работают.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage

Comment: а в iframe загружаются ресурсы из того же самого домена, что и основное окно?

Comment: Из другого домена. Это виджет.

Comment: И всё же тут не ясно. Мне нужно из iframe с помощью JS отправить событие на затемнение всего окна, т.е. на тег body главного окна. По примеру это сделать не выходит.